# Enabling SAST in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to enable the SAST in my CI/CD.  The code is in gitlab.com and we have a private runner in our AWS account.

**Gitlab Runner info:**

- Amazon Linux release 2
- Docker 18.06.1-ce
- gitlab-runner version 12.3.0

Added to my .gitlab-ci.yml per documentation

```
include:
  template: SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
```

EXPECTED: I expect to see a new sast job added to my pipeline.

ACTUAL: No new job is added, new template is ignored but existing jobs run succssfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Container wasn't running in privileged mode so I needed to add the following:

```
variables:
  SAST_DISABLE_DIND: "true"
```